# Editing mode issue in UITextfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield, uipickerview

I am using uipickerview in textfield. When I click on any text Field an uipickerview will display, and we can select any value from uipickerview.

So, my problem is that. When I click on textfield uipicker will come as well as in text field editing mode is showing. 
[image: Here is screenshot below,]

so, when i clicked on HelpTopics text field, picker is coming as well as it showing editing mode in textfield.
How solve it. I mean, i do not want that editing option mode.
When i click on textfield only picker will be show, this is I want.
How to do it ?

Comment: how you show pickerview in textfield click ? means you have putted transparent button on that OR in textfield begin method you have shown pickerview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write one line

**Swift**

```
yourTextFieldObject.tintColor = .clear // "yourTextFieldObject" is "HelpTopics" textField's object
```

**Objective-C**

```
yourTextFieldObject.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor]; // "yourTextFieldObject" is "HelpTopics" textField's object
```

But above code your **textField** cursor color will be clear and will not be display.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. It is working as per my requirement.

Comment: @KaranPatil Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3+:** Use this UITextFieldDelegate Method. Just write these line.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
            if textField == yourTextField{
                textField.resignFirstResponder()
             // Open your picker here.
            }
        }
```

Comment: By this code UIPickerView will not be displayed because OP might be added pickerView in **inputView** that's why